# How can I clear the PREROUTING rules in my iptables?

Tags: iptables, systemd

Long ago I created some prerouting rules in my iptables. I have a script in ~/myuser/Downlaods, 
 owned by `root`

```
 #!/bin/bash
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT  --to-port 8069
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT  --to-port 8070
iptables-save
```

I have commented out these lines and renamed the file and changed ownership to a non-root user.

I think I must have added it to some other script (rc.local, systemd,etc...) because after I clear the iptables, save them and reboot, the rules come back.

I have tried:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING 2
$ sudo iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING 1
$ sudo iptables-save
```

And this works temporarily. At this point the iptables are all empty. Then I reboot:

```
$ sudo reboot
```

After the reboot I get:
    $ sudo iptables -L -n -t nat

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target    prot opt source    destination
REDIRECT  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0   tcp dpt:80 redir ports 8069
REDIRECT  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0   tcp dpt:443 redir ports 8070
```

The other chains are empty.

I set systemd log level to DEBUG in the config file, and while there are thousands of lines for the boot, I don't see anything (mainly using `grep`) that refers to iptables or PREROUTING.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

I ran `$ sudo grep -rnw 'etc/init.d/' -e 'PREROUTING'` and it didn't return any results.

I ran `$ sudo grep -rnw 'etc/init.d/' -e '8069'` and it didn't return any results.

`/etc/rc.local` does not exist, so it's not running from there.

Where else can I look for this?

Comment: Install `netfilter-persistent` then remove those rules and run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure iptables-persistent`

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen that worked. Thanks. If you put that in as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Ok I have posted an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your situation install `netfilter-persistent` and then proceed to remove those rules again with your previous commands.

Now to get `iptables` to reload and be duly informed of the new state of iptables rules you either do:

```
sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
sudo ip6tables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v6 # for ipv6
```

Or:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure iptables-persistent
```